# Exit the bash function, not the terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, exit

I have a bash script as below which installs zookeeper but only if not installed already.

```
##zookeper
installZook(){

        ZOOK_VERSION="3.4.5"
        ZOOK_TOOL="zookeeper-${ZOOK_VERSION}"
        ZOOK_DOWNLOAD_URL="http://www.us.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/${ZOOK_TOOL}/${ZOOK_TOOL}.tar.gz"

        if [ -e $DEFAULT_INSTALLATION_DEST/${ZOOK_TOOL} ]; then
                echo "${ZOOK_TOOL} alreay installed";
                exit 1;      # <<<< here
        elif [ ! -e $DEFAULT_SOURCE_ROOT/${ZOOK_TOOL}.tar.gz ]; then
                wgetIt $ZOOK_DOWNLOAD_URL
        else
                echo "[info] : $DEFAULT_SOURCE_ROOT/$ZOOK_TOOL already exists"
        fi

        sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/zookeeper
        sudo mkdir -p /var/log/zookeeper

        tarIt "$DEFAULT_SOURCE_ROOT/$ZOOK_TOOL.tar.gz"
        sudo chmod 777 -R $DEFAULT_INSTALLATION_DEST/$ZOOK_TOOL
        cp $DEFAULT_INSTALLATION_DEST/$ZOOK_TOOL/conf/zoo_sample.cfg $DEFAULT_INSTALLATION_DEST/$ZOOK_TOOL/conf/zoo.cfg
cat >> ~/.bash_profile <<'EOF'

  ###############################
  ########### ZOOK ###############
  ###############################
  ZOOK_HOME=/usr/local/zookeper-3.4.5
  export ZOOK_HOME
  export PATH=$PATH:$ZOOK_HOME/bin

EOF
}
```

At the line marked `<<<< here`, if zookeeper is already installed, what I want is to exit the script below it. But using `exit` exits the terminal itself.

Comment: How do you launch this script ?

Comment: use `return 1` instead of `exit 1`

Comment: Didn't have the time to check fully out, but [builtin caller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040711) might give away how much exiting `exit` will trigger...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use `return` instead of `exit` AND run your script with `source your-script.sh` aka. `. your-script.sh`

### Full details

If launching a script with an `exit` statement in it, you have to launch it as a child of you current child.

If you launch it inside the current shell of started with your terminal session (using `. ./<scriptname>` any `exit` will close the main shell, the one started along your terminal session.

If you had launched your script like `bash ./<scriptname>` (or any other shell instead of **bash**), then `exit` would have stopped your child shell and not the one used by your terminal.

If your script has executable permissions, executing it directly without giving the name of the shell will execute it in a child shell too.

Using `return` instead of `exit` will allow you to still launch your script using `. ./<script name>` without closing the current shell. But you need to use `return` to exit from a function only or a sourced script (script ran using the `. ./<scriptname>` syntax).

Comment: `return` will NOT halt the script file

Comment: @NamGVU Returning rather than exiting is the correct thing to do. Assuming that they source the file and then call the function (the `exit`/`return` in the function would _not_ be called while sourcing the given file), the shell session would terminate (together with the terminal) if the function used `exit`.  With `return`, it would handle control back to the calling shell.  Note that if you want to return from a sourced script (which this is not about), `return` is the correct way to do that too as `exit` would terminate the shell session.

Comment: It depends on how you run the script at first place

Comment: @NamGVU There is no call to the function in the file. Just sourcing or running the file would not call the function. Explain how the function terminates the shell session and terminal in any other way than by first sourcing the file and then calling it in the terminal.

Comment: Thanjs for sharing. I think we not going too far from the topic then.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `exit 1` try using `return 1`.

Comment: `return` will return from the `InstallZook()` function, not exit the script.

Comment: @Barmar See [comment above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138730/exit-the-bash-function-not-the-terminal#comment920593_138736).

Answer (score 3):

The only way that the given script is able to terminate the shell session (and therefore the terminal) is by you sourcing the script (to install the `installZook` function in the current shell session), and then running the function in the shell.

If what you are showing is only a portion of a larger script containing a call to the `installZook` function, then the function can still only cause the terminal to terminate if the script is *sourced*, but not through being run as an ordinary shell script.

`exit` terminates the current shell session. When the function executes `exit` it terminates the shell that called it.

`return` returns from a function (or a sourced script file).  If the function, instead of `exit`, used `return`, it would return control to the calling environment (probably the interactive shell that you called the function from) without exiting it.

If you manually run the `installZook` function from the shell, then all you should need to do is to change the `exit` to `return`.  If there's another piece of code in your script that calls the function (and which you are not showing), then that piece of code needs to *additionally* react to the return status of the function.

For example

```
installZook || return
```

If this was part of no function in the script, and if you sourced the script, it would return control to the shell if the function returned a non-zero exit code.